# How can I abstract implementations away from monobehaviours?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create my first bigger project in Unity and I am struggling to understand how abstract implementations away from the monobehaviour classes attached to gameobjects.
I am very familiar with dependency injection (using ASP.NET) but it seems DI is not a great idea to include in Unity projects according to a number of different articles. These articles say Unity has to handle Inversion of Control already, which is the Service Locator principal. I cannot find any built in implementation aside from methods like `GameObject#Find` or `GameObject#GetComponent`, etc.

An example would be a class handling interaction with files:

```csharp
public interface IFileHandler { }
public class FileHandler : IFileHandler { }

public class FileHandling : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private IFileHandler fileHandler;

    private void Awake()
    {
         this.fileHandler = new FileHandler();
    }
}
```

Now the constructor of `FileHandler` changes. I would have to change it in every class.
How can I decouple the `FileHandler` from `FileHandling`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could write your own Service Locator. It's really just a singleton class with a dictionary of type to instance. You could look into Zenject or serializing interfaces with Odin Serializer but that can be a little complex.

Comment: If you look into zenject asset, it may help with your issue. It handles the creation and injection of object and can define whether a unique object is injected to many dependencies or create a new object for each dependency. As a result, if your ctor changes, it's only in the zenject file.

Comment: I have looked at zenject, but that is just DI. It sounds like the solution is to indeed just write something custom or use a hacky solution like having an initialization gameobject. Thanks regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall that in Asp.net there's `Program.cs` with main method that boots everything up. In unity you could have GameObject with similar `Program.cs` script that has been assigned a very low **Script Execution Order**. The script simply initialises your game systems if they have not been initialised yet.

During initialization you can create system instances and store to a static class like toolbox from where you can later reference them from anywhere. If your system needs to listen to unity events like update you can create a new `GameObject` with the script and set `DontDestroyOnLoad` enabled and store it to the Toolbox as well.

Toolbox is basically singleton for storing your other "singletons" so they don't have to be singletons. If you use interfaces you can easily swap out the implementation for the SaveSystem for example.

```cs
// Enum to allow multiple instances if needed
enum GameSystems { SaveSystem, GameManager }

public class GameTB {

    //usage GameTB.toolBox.SetTool(GameSystems.SaveSystem, new SaveSystem());
    public static ToolBox<GameSystems> toolBox = new ToolBox<GameSystems>();
    
    //usage GameTB.SaveSystem.SaveGame();
    public static ISaveSystem SaveSystem 
    { 
        get
        { 
            return toolBox.GetTool<ISaveSystem>(GameSystems.SaveSystem); 
        }
    }
    
    public static IGameManager GameManager 
    { 
        get
        { 
            return toolBox.GetTool<IGameManager>(GameSystems.GameManager); 
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class ToolBox<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, object> Tools { get; } = new Dictionary<T, object>();

    public K GetTool<K>(T key)
    {
        if (Tools.ContainsKey(key))
            return (K)Tools[key];
        else
            return default(K);
    }

    public void SetTool(T key, object tool)
    {
        if (!Tools.ContainsKey(key))
            Tools[key] = tool;
        else
            Tools.Add(key, tool);
    }

    public bool ContainsTool(T key)
    {
        if (Tools.ContainsKey(key) && Tools[key] != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void ClearTools()
    {
        Tools.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: However for bigger game projects instead of thinking too much about abstractions and design patterns you should focus on thinking what tools and systems you need to make so that even designers with little to no coding experience could make levels, simple game logic, dialogue, add music and sounds etc. If such tools already exists use them in your project.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It sounds like building a custom implementation for this is the way to go.

Comment: It's one way to go but there are some amazing things you can do with `MonoBehaviors` and `ScriptableObjects`. Using custom implementations is fine for things where you don't need or want to use features of Unity but can easily lead to [overengineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering) and underutilisation of inspector, asset database and Unity Editor in general.

Comment: I will dive deeper into scriptable objects to see if they can fulfill my needs. Thank you again, it looks like that advice is a great starting point for me.

Comment: No problem. There's  a lot more to them than one might get from reading the basic tutorials. Here's one interesting [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk) from Unity 2017 about them. They're also often used to solve problems Unity has with polymorphism and serialization.